# Divide a range of cells with a particular number if cell values are numeric

Tags: excel, vba

I have to divide all the cell values of sheet -"Databook" with a number 1000000 only if the cell contains numeric value. It means I have to divide only those cells in the sheet which contains numbers like 17577.2 , 2123, 13979123.22, 239812098321.1, and 9798.

```
Sub i()

'declare variables
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim myVal As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = ws.Range("A:Z")
For Each myVal In rng

If IsNumeric(myVal) = True Then

myVal = myVal.Value / 1000000

Else

Next myVal

End Sub
```

Comment: Please include what you have tried in your question, and explain the problem you ran into.

Comment: Hi , I tried something like this     Sub i()

'declare variables
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim myVal As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = ws.Range("A:Z")
For Each myVal In rng

If IsNumeric(myVal) = True Then

myVal = myVal.Value / 1000000

Else

Next myVal

End Sub

Comment: Could you include that code into your question? That would make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently suffer from a missing `End If`, thus your current code won't run at all. Properly indenting your code would have revealed the issue. I would also recommend not trying to loop all cells in your current range. Note that these are (for Excel 2019 at least) 27.262.976 cells to go through (you might want to first find your range of interest first; last used row, last used column). This many calls will be terribly slow. Limit that numbers by just using the actual numeric values at least.

Try to uitilize [`SpecialCells`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells). The way it works > `<YourRange>.SpecialCells(XlCellType, [XlSpecialCellsValue])`. For example:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

For Each cl In ws.Range("A:Z").SpecialCells(2, 1)
    cl.Value = cl.Value / 1000000
Next

End Sub
```

Where: `.SpecialCells(2, 1)` can also be read as `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)`

**Note:** If you have big chunks of cells that contain numeric values it might be beneficial to loop `Areas` property instead of `Cells` since you can load these into an array and perform calculations in memory before pasting back these values. This could also save you some valuable runtime.

Comment: Thankyou so much this worked. Also one more thing if after dividing the cells I need to apply the comma style plus decreasing the decimal by two places in the same cell value. I am using this.                Range("A:Z").CurrentRegion.NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"

Comment: Well, you can try to do that in a single go: `ws.Range("A:Z").SpecialCells(2, 1).NumberFormat = "0.00"`. If that is not what you need, you might want to consider opening another question where you explain in detail what it is you want with example data and expected results. Glad this has at least answered your current question.

Comment: Hey , thankyou so much. Your solution worked correctly